# Array's length in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, size

How I could determine the number of elements from an array in Matlab, without using functions such as length(), size(), etc. ?
Thanks you !

Comment: Why not just use `size`?

Comment: Create a while loop and increase the iterator until you hit the dimension of the number of elements in an array

Comment: @Metahominid how would he know the `dimension of the number of elements` if he doesn't use length(),size(), etc. He can use a loop and check for the end with `end` keyword

Comment: @pkpkpk  because if attempts to select from an array dimension that doesn't exist he will get an error and you'll know that the array dimension preceding it is the terminal dimension.

Comment: Use `numel`? Honestly, this is a weird question. It would help if you added some motivation. Why not use these functions?

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment. It might not be, but it sounds like one. ["3. Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having solving it.**"](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The current state of your question doesn't fulfill these requirements. Please [edit] the question to improve it. Please, also read this [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is to iterate over the cells until an empty cell is encountered. I have taken two variables for iteration namely, **i** and **j**. **i** is for rows and **j** is for columns.

Initially set the value of i and j as `i=1` and `j=1`. Now in a `while` loop **iterate by incrementing j** and **keeping i = 1 as constant**.

** First *try* to copy that cell in a variable **x**. If that cell is an empty cell an error will pop up. Aim is to take advantage of this error using **try/catch** statements.

Scince the statement `x = vec(i,j);` is written in the `try` block so on encountering an empty cell instead of `try` the `catch` block will be executed where `flag = 0` makes the flag 0, this will cause the while loop to end.

So, we have the number of columns stored in `j` and the `while` loop terminates on encountering an empty cell.

```
flag = 1;
i = 1;  
j = 1;

while(flag==1)     % loop will continue till flag is 1 (or say flag is HIGH)
    try
        x = vec(i,j);  % Try to copy this cell of array vec in x
        j = j+1;       % if successful to copy then increment value of j else catch block is executed
    catch
        flag = 0;      % Set flag = 0 (or low) to end the while loop
    end
end

j = j - 1;    % The value of j comes out to be one greater than number of columns hence decrementing by 1

%
% WE HAVE THE NUMBER OF COLUMNS !!
%



% WE WILL PERFORM SAME THING TO GET THE NUMBER OF ROWS BY INCREMENTING i AND 
% KEEPING j AS CONSTANT

flag=1;

while(flag==1)
    try
        x = vec(i,j);
        i = i+1;
    catch
        flag = 0;
    end
end

i = i - 1;

% i is the number of rows in the matrix or array
% j is the number of columns in the matrix

dim = [i,j]   % vector named dim(or say matrix named dim) contains the required output
```

`dim` contains the size of *vec*